# How does $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}{p}-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(1-x_i)}{1-p} \rightarrow p = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, probability-distributions

How does $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}{p}-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(1-x_i)}{1-p}=0 \rightarrow p = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$

I'm reading lecture slides on taking the derivative of a Bernoulli distriubtion and the set the derivative: $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}{p}-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(1-x_i)}{1-p} = 0.$ Then they derive $p$ as such. I don't know how they got the simplified expression $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it very clear, let $$s = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$$ be the sample total.  Then we observe $$\sum_{i=1}^n (1 - x_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n 1 - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = n - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = n - s.$$  So your equation becomes $$\frac{s}{p} - \frac{n-s}{1-p} = 0,$$ from which we find $$p(n-s) = s(1-p),$$ hence $$((n-s)+s)p = s,$$ or $$p = \frac{s}{n} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i.$$  This is just elementary algebra.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply by $p(1-p)$ on both sides to nix the denominators and do a small amount of algebra to get the answer from there.